# z-index property not getting retrieved while other properties are getting retrieved by the same helper function

Tags: javascript, css, dom, browser, z-index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20000;http://new-url/" id="meta-refresh">
<style type="text/css">
#test{
width: 100px;
height: 80px;
background-color: yellow;
opacity:0.5;
z-index:3;

}
</style>
  <title>Add Properties</title>
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit-1.12.0.css"-->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test">This is some text</div>
  <p>Properties</p>
  <script>
  function getStyle(el, cssprop){
 if (el.currentStyle) //IE
  return el.currentStyle[cssprop]
 else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) //Firefox
  return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "")[cssprop]
 else //try and get inline style
  return el.style[cssprop]
}
    console.log("1"+navigator.appVersion);
    console.log("2"+navigator.platform);
    console.log("3"+history.length);
    console.log("4"+parent.top.document.referrer);
     metatags = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");  
   var content = metatags[0].getAttribute("content");
    var mr = document.getElementById("meta-refresh");
    console.log("Meta Refresh"+ content);
    console.log(navigator.plugins);
    console.log(navigator.plugins.length);
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("test");
    console.log(getStyle(mydiv,'width'));
    console.log(getStyle(mydiv,'opacity'));
    console.log(getStyle(mydiv,'z-index'));
    var d = new Date()
    var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
    console.log(n);


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code and all properties like width opacity show appropriate values but z-index gives out an **undefined** value.I tried 'z-index' as well as "zindex".Please help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance
Swaraj

Comment: `console.log(mydiv.css("z-index"));`

Comment: Did you try `zIndex`, as hyphenated properties are camel-cased in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried `z-index` as well as `zindex`

Close, but it's `zIndex`. Properties of [CSSStyleDeclarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) (such as returned by `.style` or `getComputedStyle()`) are camel-cased. You also could use `.getPropertyValue("z-index")`.